# Can you play all the Diablo 2 acts on Diablo 2 Lord of Destruction?

Tags: diablo-ii

If I have both Diablo 2 and the expansion pack: Diablo 2 : Lord of Destruction installed, can I play the Diablo 2 acts on the expansion pack?

The reason is, I've heard that the expansion pack has a lot of gameplay improvements, if so, I want to play it rather than the original Diablo 2.

Comment: fyi: you need the original D2 cd's for the install. the expansion is only a single cd and does not contain the original d2 acts or game files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The LoD expansion expands the original game - it includes everything in it, but adds more content such as new classes and a new act. It does not replace the existing acts, so the answer to your question is **yes**, you can play all the D2 acts on D2:LoD.

If you have Lord of Destruction there's not much reason for you to run the regular D2 (unless you want to play online with friends that don't own it, if I recall correctly - it's been a while).

Comment: Technically the expansion doesn't include everything in the original game.  It only contains ACT 5.  You still need the original game installed, but you only need to run the expansion.

Comment: You can, however, play the first four acts as one of the new character classes from the expansion.

Comment: If memory serves, you can play LoD online with people who don't have it, however, you cannot host the game in a LAN environment, and on Battle.net, none of the item drops will be from LoD, and trading LoD items is disabled with those who don't own the expansion.

Comment: I heard some of the old unique items from the original Diablo 2 are pretty powerful. So that might be one reason to play the original.

Comment: @john2x: You would also be able to get them playing the expansion.  Their tiny drop rate would just be smaller, that's all.